# Error instalando neuralcoref

Tags: python, spacy, cython, watson

Obtengo este error:

```
ERROR: Could not open requirements file: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'requirements.txt'
ERROR: File "setup.py" not found. Directory cannot be installed in editable mode: /home/dsxuser/work
```

Al ejecutar este codigo en Watson

```
!venv .env
!source .env/bin/activate
!git clone https://github.com/huggingface/neuralcoref.git
!cd neuralcoref
!pip install -r requirements.txt
!pip install -e .
```

Comment: Ejecutando *qué comando* obtienes ese error? Por favor edita tu pregunta con el enlace editar que está justo debajo de las etiquetas y añade la información pertinente

Comment: Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes.

Comment: Cuando dices que corres esto en watson, ¿estás usando Watson studio? instalaste el paquete en python usando `pip install --upgrade "ibm-watson>=4.5.0"` o algo así? Lo otro, qué dice pip.log?

Answer (score 1):

Lo primero: si no se encuentra el archivo requirements.txt, no hay mucho que hacer. ¿Estás trabajando en un virtualenv? Si es así, tendrías que comenzar por generar el archivo usando `pip freeze > requirements.txt`. Si no es el caso, tienes que ejecutar ese `pip install -r` en el directorio donde ese archivo sí exista.

Cuando haces `pip install -e .`, el `-e` crea enlaces simbólicos que posiblemente no tengas permisos para hacer.

Es muy probable que debas hacer `pip install .` en su lugar.

(Con base en: [respuesta de SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57682200/236345))

Comment: El error persiste.

Comment: @StalinFigueroaÁlava pues edité la respuesta pero no hay mucho más que ésto. Revisa la estructura del proyecto que clonaste.

Comment: Hola Alfabravo, mi amigo gracias por tu ayuda, retome el tema, y te confirmo; estoy trabajando en IBM-watson que es virtual, ejecute pip freeze > requirements.txt como me indicas, pero ahora se presenta otro mensaje de error.

Comment: Requirement already satisfied: wheel<1.0,>=0.23.0 in /opt/conda/envs/Python36/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from astunparse==1.6.2->-r requirements.txt (line 10)) (0.32.3)
ERROR: Directory '.' is not installable. Neither 'setup.py' nor 'pyproject.toml' found.

Comment: Este es el codigo ejecutado. !venv .env
!source .env/bin/activate
!git clone https://github.com/huggingface/neuralcoref.git
!cd neuralcoref
!pip freeze > requirements.txt
!pip install -r requirements.txt
!pip install .